# Handling multi-dimensional array lengths in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, return, return-value

I would like to build a function that takes a multidimensional array and prints it like a grid. I'm having trouble with it because c++ doesn't allow a function to have a multidimensional array argument unless you specify its length. There is a question about it on  here, that was answered using vectors. I haven't learned how to use vectors yet, so please don't use them in an answer, or at least provide a good tutorial on them if you do.

Anyway, I was wondering if it's possible to return an array in c++... I started programming with javascript, so the first solution I thought of was to do something like

```
int gen(int len){
    return int arr(int a[][len]){
        cout << a[0][0];
    };
}
```

I knew it wouldn't work, tried it, and wasn't surprised when it didn't. Is there a way to do something like this though?

Comment: It will take you an hour of reading and an hour of experimentation to learn how to use vectors.  Or alternatively, you can spend many hours cooking up your own class to handle all of the details that aren't built native arrays.  I think that if the best solution is one you haven't learned yet, your time is best spent learning it.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/ or http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++STL.html  Arrays are useful, but with more powerful tools available, it's often best to take advantage of the power unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: @DavidO STL vectors don't support multidimensional arrays though... (vector<vector <T> > doesn't really count, since that is still a 1D array, just with an item type that is also a 1D array; in particular it doesn't behave like the requested 2D grid unless you manually resize all the vector<T>'s yourself)

Comment: @DavidO Thanks for the link to the yolinux tutorials ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you can pass array by reference. With making an array a `template`, it's possible to receive any length in the function. For example,

```
template<size_t SIZE1>
void print (int (&arr)[SIZE1])
{ ... }

template<size_t SIZE1, size_t SIZE2>
void print (int (&arr)[SIZE1][SIZE2])
{ ... }

template<size_t SIZE1, size_t SIZE2, size_t SIZE3>
void print (int (&arr)[SIZE1][SIZE2][SIZE3])
{ ... }
```

This pattern will internally create a unique function for every different size of array. It offers ease of use, but may increase the code size.

Comment: Templates work with just about any compile-time values. For this to work, the templates would have to use numeic constants for the values, you could not use values determined at runtime. If you declare fixed-length arrays and pass them to the templated functions, the compiler can usually work out the needed template values for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the size of the array, there's no way around it. `std::vector` is the correct way to solve this, and you can find a good reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/). That allows passing only the vector, as it knows its own length and the function can ask it, making it similar to what you're used to from Javascript.

Otherwise, you **must** pass the size of the array to the function one way or another.

One way is using templates, but that would not work on dynamic arrays (and is a bit wasteful, as it creates a copy of the function per each array size used). The other is just adding an additional parameter to the function, with the size.